# Jetpack compose text styling

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textstyle

In my current project utilizing Jetpack Compose, I'm tasked with enabling users to input data while also providing functionality to style text with options like bold or italic upon clicking buttons. Given my novice level in Jetpack Compose, I'm seeking guidance on how to implement this feature effectively.

```
 @Composable
 fun CustomTextField() {


var isBold by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
val prevPos by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

Column() {


    Button(onClick = {
        isBold = !isBold
    }) {
        Text(text = "Toggle Bold")
    }

    TextField(
        value = textState.value,
        onValueChange = {

            if (isBold) {
                val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                    append(it.text)

                    addStyle(
                        SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                        prevPos,
                        it.text.length
                    )
                }

                textState.value =  it.copy(annotatedString, it.selection, it.composition)
            } else {
                textState.value =  it
            }
        },
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            lineHeight = 24.sp,
            color = Color.Black
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
    )
    }

 }
```

I am trying through this but my whole text get bold after click on button

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using [withStyle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/style-text#multiple-styles)?

Comment: I was using withStyle in visualTransformation . When i click on button i makes whole text bold not next text . So any tip how i can achive this

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve? Adding screenshots or images of before/after might help.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the context which you provide.. I think this is better solution from what you have.

- You dont have to use the **buildAnnotatedString**
- You should be use the style within the TextField is base practice

**Note:**
I am using Material3

Here is the code:

```
var isBold by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
StackoverflowTheme {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column {
            Button(onClick = {
                isBold = !isBold
            }) {
                Text(text = "Toggle Bold")
            }
            TextField(
                value = textState.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    textState.value = it
                },
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    lineHeight = 24.sp,
                    color =  Color.Black,
                    fontWeight = if (isBold) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is render result:
[image]

Comment: but the problem is that when i click on bold button it make whole text bold but i want the text as nomal next text should be bold like  i am typing 
                             jetpack
after that i will click on bold button next text should be bold not all like
                    compose
 should be bold not
jetpack compose